# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input aaaabbaa

Tags: java, string, palindrome

**Code is to print the longest palindrome in a string**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG 
{
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int max=0;
        String s= br.readLine();
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t-->0)
        {
            String w=" ",x=" ";
            int l=s.length();
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                char c=s.charAt(i);
                w=w+c;
                x=c+x;
                if(w.equalsIgnoreCase(x))
                {
                    if(w.length()>max)
                    {
                        max=w.length();

                    }
                }
                if(x.length()>max)
                System.out.println(x);
                w=" ";
                x=" ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I AM GETTING THIS ERROR for input "aaaabbaa"

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "aaaabbaa"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at GFG.main(File.java:14)**

I am new to java and get this error in every program on the web page compiler

Please teach me where I am going wrong

Comment: Would be helpful if you told us what this code is meant to accomplish :) .

Comment: Your code asks for a string and then a number, did you write "aaaabbaa" as first input or as second?

Comment: Seems like you should just move the string s=br.readLine() at the beginning of the while loop. Your code is reading a string and then a number, but in fact, based solely on how the custom input looks, you should be reading a number and then read that number of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should check `br.readLine()` for null value. You're calling it twice, but there's only one line in your input, so the second time it returns null, and `Integer.parseInt` cannot process it and throws error.

Answer (score 1):

At first you got input as  string then you convert string to int using Integer.parseInt(), java not able to convert string to int data type directly.

Integer.parseInt() method accept only numeric constant like 123 but you pass as abc input so java not able convert that alphabet to int directly using Integer.parseInt() so it’s throws NumberFormatException.

If you try to get constant from user and convert to int means please use the following code :

```
int x, y;
String[] input;
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String str = br.readLine();
  input = str.split(" ");

  x = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
  y = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
```

I hope it helps you thanks

Comment: **Yes it worked the error is gone but I am getting wrong output For Input:
1
aaaabbaa
My Output is:
a a a a b b a a **

Comment: @AdityaJaiswal Great can you share your final code I will help you

Answer (score 0):

The statement int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); throw exception because when the method br.readLine() return a value which are not convertible into numeric(integer).
The parameter value of the method Integer.parseInt() must be a string which can be convertible into integer.
If you want to get the length of the input string the just use int t = s.length; after the statement String s = br.readLine();

Comment: **Yes it worked the error is gone but I am getting wrong output For Input:
1
aaaabbaa
My Output is:
a a a a b b a a **

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your post I did't see "what is the purpose of your code? I mean what are you doing in code" I just see the error on very top of the code and I put my solution for you. Now I see the purpose.. for best solution go for dynamic programming
This solution is efficient and I have tested it on LeetCode. Try it

```
 public String longestPalindrome(String str) {
        if(str.isEmpty()) {
          return "";
        }
    int n = str.length();
    int longestStr = 0, start = 0, end = 0;
    boolean[][] palindrom = new boolean[n][n];

    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      palindrom[j][j] = true;
      for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
         if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j) && (j-i <= 2 || palindrom[i+1][j-1])) {
          palindrom[i][j] = true;
          if(j-i+1 > longestStr) {
            longestStr = j-i+1;
            start = i;
            end = j;
          }  
        }
      }
    }   
    return str.substring(start, end+1);

}
```